# Call on different constructor with 'default' HashMap

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I had a lot of testcases running on the class MyClass, using it's default constructor: MyClass().

Now the requirements of MyClass changed and the user can provide a HashMap to indicate some pairs . Now a MyClass needs to have at least one pair  and throws exceptions if one of those is null.

I was hoping to create another default constructor to avoid having to rewrite all the test methods something like:

```
public MyClass() {

  HashMap<KeyClass, ValueClass> hashMap = HashMap<KeyClass, ValueClass>();
  hashMap.put(KeyClass.someValue, new ValueClass());
  this(hashMap);

}
```

Now this doesn't work, because i have to call the other constructor first, so i thought of writing some method

```
private static HashMap<KeyClass, ValueClass> getDefaultHashmap();
```

and using it to call the other constructor like this:

```
public MyClass() {

  this(MyClass.getDefaultHashmap());

}
```

But this seemed to me as not really good style, so i was hoping you could tell me what the right way to do something like this is!

Comment: If you're trying to add test data in your tested class (I mean create a default HashMap in MyClass in order to test it) I think it's a bad idea. The best is to use the constructor with the HashMap anbd to provide it from your tests.

Comment: Actually i run tests on other methods that were present prior to the change, so they are totally independent of the hashmap

Comment: Right, but do you really need to have kind of a default hashMap in MyClass or is it just because you are facing a problem for the tests?

Comment: No, i don't really need a default constructor, it is indeed a question of handiness, i was of course also interested how i could manage this if it would be 100% required to have a default constructor. And last but not least, i might have to change more stuff later so to not have to break open old testcases too much i was planning on always providing a default constructor, to also be sure, no exceptions are thrown all of a sudden or so :)

Comment: I'm with reef - if the intended usage pattern for your class does not require a default constructor, then I would argue against adding one just to save work in your unit tests. Presumably there would be nothing to stop a user of your class from calling this default constructor which would probably give behaviour that you are not expecting?

Comment: But the documentation gives the user guarantees of what the use of the default constructor will imply, so if the user applies the default constructor he has an exact description of the object he created and the postconditions that object fulfills. Doesn't that exclude unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could inline the HashMap creation:

```
public MyClass() {
    this(new HashMap<KeyClass, ValueClass>() {{
        put(KeyClass.someValue, new ValueClass());
    }});
}
```

But you'd have to ignore the serial-id warning to keep it "pretty".

Comment: Thanks awesome! I'll accept your answer as soon as the time limit has run out :)

Comment: You're welcome - and @Peter: i'm usually still typing when i see "4 new answers posted" flash up! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go with creating a `new HashMap(...)` in both constructors, and not try to wrap the creation in a new static method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that I typically use:

```
public MyClass {

  private static Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> newMap() {
     Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> result = new HashMap<KeyClass, ValueClass>();
     result.put(KeyClass.someValue, new ValueClass());
     return result; 
  }

  public MyClass() {
     this(newMap());
  }

  public MyClass(Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> m) { ... }
}
```

I prefer it over subclassing the `HashMap`-class (as suggested by @alpian) - Seems cleaner, and also does not create the risk of breaking the contract of the equals() method (described here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization)

Comment: How does it break the contract of the equals() method?

Comment: It does not happen with HashMap, but with other classes (whose equals() method checks the type of the other operand by invoking .getClass()), such problems may happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating a new anonymous HashMap subclass, and only need one pair, and don't want to make a new static method, you could do this:

```
public MyClass() {
    this(new HashMap<KeyClass, ValueClass>(
        Collections.singletonMap(KeyClass.someValue, new ValueClass())));
}
```

If your other constructor takes a Map and copies it, you may not even need to crate the HashMap

```
public MyClass() {
    this(Collections.singletonMap(KeyClass.someValue, new ValueClass()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed probably the cleaner way, the only thing is that alpian's method i can add more elements, so it comes in handy. I agree though, this is probably the most elegant solution for just one element.